# EE 2.2.2, member group unable to access file manager

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I have a site running ee 2.2.2. I've set up a new member group, but this group cannot see the file manager or upload files.

I've checked the group settings as below:

Can access CONTENT: File Manager - yes
Can administrate file upload preferences - yes

I've gone into file manager and made sure the group can access the directory.

If they go to Content menu, they can't see the file option.  If they click Browse Server in an entry, they get the following message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to ensure that member group has access to `upload files`:

[image]

That's found under `Content > Files > Files Upload Preferences > Edit the upload path` at the bottom of the page.

Also you shouldn't need to give them `Can access CONTENT: File Manager - yes Can administrate file upload preferences - yes`

Just `Can access CONTENT: File Manager` under Group Preferences is all that's needed.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your help.  That was my first thought, but the file upload preferences look to be correct.  I gave them access to everything that mentioned files in group settings to see if that helped, but no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: HI Mark, no solution I'm afraid, but I got around it by creating a new member group with the same permissions and assigning the existing members to it.  I'm thinking it's a bug in EE 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a bug in EE 2.2.2.  I created a new member group, moved the accounts across to the new group, with the same permissions and it appears to be all ok now.